# Numeric sorting based on numbers rather than digits

Tags: sorting

I would like to perform a numeric sort on a file of non-negative integers based on the first column; so I am looking at `sort -n`. But for those rows which have the same value in their first column, I would also like ordering to defer to the number in the second column etc.

For example, with this input:

```
8 4
8 8
8 16
4 4
4 8
4 16
16 4
16 8
16 16
```

I would like to get:

```
4 4
4 8
4 16
8 4
8 8
8 16
16 4
16 8
16 16
```

...but instead I get:

```
4 16
4 4
4 8
8 16
8 4
8 8
16 16
16 4
16 8
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: A stable sort appears to create the sought output: `sort -ns`.